# ¿Por qué recibo el error "Couldn't fetch mysqli"?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Recibo un mensaje de error:

> Warning: mysqli_query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\xampp\htdocs\ProyectoYuli\PVotacion\config\proceso.php on line 24

en este código:

```
<?php

    //require("conexion.php");

        $connect = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "elecciones") or die('Error al conectar'. mysqli_errno($connect));
        mysqli_close($connect);

    /*Datos*/
    $nombre= $_POST['nombre'];
    $apellido = $_POST['apellido'];
//LOGO-SLOGAN   
    $slogan = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['slogan']['tmp_name']));
//foto
    $foto = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['foto']['tmp_name']));
    $n_documento = $_POST['n_documento']; 
    $cargo = $_POST['cargo'];
    $n_tarjeton = $_POST['n_tarjeton'];
    $color = $_POST['color_tarje'];
    $descripcion = $_POST['descripcion'];

        /*INSERCCION*/



$query= "INSERT INTO candidato(nombres, apellidos, slogan, foto, n_documento, cargo, n_candidato, color_tarjeton, descripcion) VALUES('$nombre', '$apellido', '$slogan', '$foto', '$n_documento', '$cargo', '$n_tarjeton', '$color', '$descripcion')";

        $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);   

?>
```

¿Cuál es mi error?¿Qué puedo hacer para solucionarlo?

Comment: Este código puede sufrir ataques de inyección SQL. Usar MySQL/PDO es un buen paso para evitarlos, pero deberías utilizar sentencias preparadas en lugar de SQL dinámicas.

Comment: El titulo de la pregunta no te va a generar muchas respuestas porque no define para nada tu problema. Si pones un mejor titulo, te generará muchas más respuestas.

Comment: tambien me pasó que cerraba la conexion antes de tiempo

Answer (score 9):

```
mysqli_close($connect);
```

Seguido del

```
$connect = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "elecciones") or die('Error al conectar'. mysqli_errno($connect));
```

Estás cerrando la conexión antes de usarla. Tu código debería verse así:

```
<?php

    //require("conexion.php");

    $connect = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "elecciones") or die('Error al conectar'. mysqli_errno($connect));


    /*Datos*/
    $nombre= $_POST['nombre'];
    $apellido = $_POST['apellido'];
    //LOGO-SLOGAN   
    $slogan = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['slogan']['tmp_name']));
    //foto
    $foto = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['foto']['tmp_name']));
    $n_documento = $_POST['n_documento']; 
    $cargo = $_POST['cargo'];
    $n_tarjeton = $_POST['n_tarjeton'];
    $color = $_POST['color_tarje'];
    $descripcion = $_POST['descripcion'];

    /*INSERCCION*/

    $query= "INSERT INTO candidato(nombres, apellidos, slogan, foto, n_documento, cargo, n_candidato, color_tarjeton, descripcion) VALUES('$nombre', '$apellido', '$slogan', '$foto', '$n_documento', '$cargo', '$n_tarjeton', '$color', '$descripcion')";

    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);   

    mysqli_close($connect);

?>
```