# Warning: mysqli::query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Me muestra este error:

> "Warning: mysqli::query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in 
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\prac_01\html\php\tabla.php on line 28
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc()
>   on null  in C:\xampp\htdocs\prac_01\html\php\tabla.php:29 Stack trace:
>   0 {main}  thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\prac_01\html\php\tabla.php on line 29"

Este es mi código:

```
    $query="SELECT * FROM table_3";
    $resultado= $conexion->query($query);
    while($row= $resultado->fetch_assoc()){
```

Gracias de antemano.

Edito (código conexión):

```
<?php
    $usuario = "root";
    $password = "";
    $servidor = "localhost";
    $basededatos = "test_02";
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "test_02");
    $conexion = mysqli_connect( $servidor, $usuario, "" ) or die ("Error: No se ha podido conectar al servidor.");
    $db = mysqli_select_db( $conexion, $basededatos ) or die ( "Error: No se ha podido conectar a la base de datos." );
    mysqli_close( $conexion );
?>
```

Comment: Hola @Breath, puedes poner tu código donde tengas la conexión?

Comment: Ya lo añadí al cuerpo del hilo. Perdón, tuve problemas para añadir el código completo.

Comment: Esta línea sobra: `$db = mysqli_select_db( $conexion, $basededatos ) or die ( "Error: No se ha podido conectar a la base de datos." );` (ya seleccionaste la base de datos en el comando `new`) ...  y además, estás cerrando la conexión nada más abrirla: `mysqli_close( $conexion );`, por lo que en cualquier código la conexión será nula. Tienes que cerrarla del otro lado, una vez hayas hecho la consulta y obtenido los datos.

Comment: Cierto eso que dice @A.Cedano

Comment: @A.Cedano Gracias por tu respuesta. Entonces, ¿debería eliminar esa línea y colocar el cierre de conexión más adelante?

Comment: Sí, debes cerrarla en el código que usa la conexión, después de haber obtenido los datos. Tienes más fallos. Por ejemplo, aquí: `$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "test_02");` ya deberías tener un objeto de conexión. Usa solamente eso: `$mysqli` y olvídate de todo lo demás, lo puedes borrar. Luego en tu código usas la variable `$mysqli` o la cambias por `$conexion`. En realidad estás conectando dos veces como bien apunta @foursixnine

Comment: Muchas gracias, @A.Cedano . Estoy de prácticas y no tengo ninguna base de PHP ni de ningún lenguaje. Estoy intentando aprender buscando en internet y debo tener mil fallos. Muchas gracias por vuestra paciencia.

Comment: Bienvenido. Aquí aprenderás mucho y cuando te bases en código antiguo o inseguro (que abunda mucho por ahí en tutoriales) aquí habrá alguien que te dirá: *Oye, ese código está obsoleto, o es inseguro, mejor implementa esta solución*. De modo que estás en uno de los mejores sitios para aprender. Saludos.

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Por qué recibo el error "Couldn't fetch mysqli"?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/14130/por-qu%c3%a9-recibo-el-error-couldnt-fetch-mysqli)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Realmente estás creando dos conexiones.

Una aquí:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "test_02");
```

Y otra aquí:

```
$conexion = mysqli_connect( $servidor, $usuario, "" ) or die ("Error: No se ha podido conectar al servidor.");
$db = mysqli_select_db( $conexion, $basededatos ) or die ( "Error: No se ha podido conectar a la base de datos." );
```

Luego, estás cerrando una de las conexiones que creas y que es precisamente la que usas del otro lado:

```
mysqli_close( $conexion );
```

### Recomendaría que

Uses una sola conexión, dando preferencia al estilo orientado a objetos<sup>1</sup>. Y que uses las variables, si las has declarado es para usarlas:

```
<?php
$usuario = "root";
$password = "";
$servidor = "localhost";
$basededatos = "test_02";
$mysqli = new mysqli($servidor, $usuario, $password, $basededatos);
/*Esto es importante para evitar problemas con acentos*/
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
?>
```

Ya que hemos dejado el nombre de la conexión como `$mysqli`, entonces en el código usarás ese nombre.

```
$query="SELECT * FROM table_3";
$resultado= $mysqli->query($query);  //aquí usamos ahora $mysqli
while($row= $resultado->fetch_assoc()){
    //manejar resultados
}
/*Es aquí donde hay que cerrar la conexión*/
$mysqli->close();
```

---

**Notas:**

<sup>1</sup> <sub>En muchos aspectos PHP admite dos estilos de programación: *procedural* y *orientado a objetos*, tal es el caso de `mysqli`. No se recomienda mezclar estilos. Aunque el código funciona, se hace difícil de mantener y de comprender. El estilo *orientado a objetos* es más moderno, más intuitivo y más elegante que el estilo procedural, requiere menos código (muchas funciones del estilo procedural son horriblemente extensas). Aunque eres libre de elegir uno u otro estilo, recomendaría siempre usar el estilo orientado a objetos. Para más detalles sobre esto [puedes consultar esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/85852/29967).</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Es posible que estes cerrando la conexion antes de ejecutar el query. Preferiblemente asegurate de añadirlo al final de tu codigo.

Tambien parece (segun lo que leo) que tienes codigo procedural y codigo orientado a objetos mezclado. Revisa los ejemplos en el manual de PHP: http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php que quizas te den un poco mas de luz en lo que estas intentando hacer.