# conexiones a base de datos con sesiones en PHP

Tags: php, mysqli, session

Por medio de uso de $_SESSION guardo un objeto que que se conecta a la base de datos, ello con el fin de mantener mantener conexión a la base de datos mientras el usuario se encuentre inciado sesión.

Cuando mando a llamar a la base de datos desde otro script PHP me manda mysqli_query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli.

Agradecería mucha su ayuda.

Aca el codigo:

**login.php**

```
$db = new DataBase();

$user = array(
"nombre"=>"Juan",
"id" => "123456"
);

$_SESSION["usr"] = array( 
        "nombre" => $usr["nombre"],
        "id" => $usr["id"],
        "db" => serialize($db)
    );
```

**myArticles.php**

```
session_start();
$db =  unserialize($_SESSION["usr"]["db"]);
$art = $db->getAllArticlesView($_SESSION["usr"]["id"]);
```

**DabaBase.php**

```
    class DataBase(){
...

      function getAllArticlesView($userId){
            if($this->erroDB) return false;

            //Se obtienen todos los articulos
            $consulta = "SELECT titulo, categoria, fecha, img_describe FROM articulo WHERE id = '{$userId}'; ";
            $respuesta = mysqli_query($this->conexion, $consulta);
            if($respuesta == false) return false;

            $respuesta = mysqli_fetch_all($respuesta);
            return $respuesta;
        }
   ...

    }
```

Cuando mando a llamar a getAllArticles() me sale  Warning: mysqli_query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli  cuando el método llega a la línea donde manda a llamar a la función mysqli_query()

Tal vez la lógica que uso no sea la correcta, quería evitar estar creando y cerrando conexón con la base datos por cada escript que se conecte a la base de datos. Agradecería mucho sus comentarios al respecto de ésto.

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Warning: mysqli::query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/214994/warning-mysqliquery-couldnt-fetch-mysqli)

Comment: No aportas el código completo así que no se si el error es lo que voy a decirte: considera añadir session_start() en todo fichero en el que quieras usar las variables session, incluído en el fichero login ya que ahí haces una asignación.

Comment: Creo que te equivocas en esto: *`Tal vez la lógica que uso no sea la correcta, quería evitar estar creando y cerrando conexón con la base datos por cada escript que se conecte a la base de datos.`* Es mucho más costoso y quizá más peligroso, estar cargando con una conexión a la base de datos para arriba y para abajo. Es mucho más simple conectar allí donde necesites y punto. Imagina un contexto de usuarios concurrentes donde diez mil usuarios se conecta cada uno y carga con la conexión manteniéndola activa para hacer algo con ella dentro de 5, 10 o 20 minutos o 1 hora... Saca tus conclusiones.

Answer (score 0):

No todos los objetos pueden ser serializados. En general, los objetos internos de PHP, incluyendo el resource devuelto al abrir una conexión [MySQLi](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.mysqli.php) no son serializables a menos que implementen la interfaz [Serializable](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.serializable.php), que no es el caso.

PHP está pensado como un ciclo que recrea todo en cada request. Abrir una conexión es barato. Las conexiones abiertas a la BBDD "durmiendo" en cambio son un recurso escaso.