# Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\SalyArtOfi\logins.php on line 63

Tags: php, crud

los errores son lo siguientes:

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\SalyArtOfi\logins.php on line 63

-Esta es la línea 63:

```
$resultado = mysqli_query($query, $conexion);
```

Y este es el segundo error:

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\SalyArtOfi\logins.php on line 74

-Línea 74:

```
<?php while($filas= mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
 ?>
```

Este es el código en general:
donde llamo la conexion ->

```
<?php 
    include '3conn.php';
    $query = "SELECT Id,gmail,password FROM datosg";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($query, $conexion);
    ?> `
    <div>
    <tr>
   <th>ID</th>
   <th>Gmail</th>
   <th>Password</th>
   <th>Operaciones</th>
   </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
```

Donde se supone que deberia de estar buscando lo que hay en la variable resultado: ->

```
 <?php while($filas= mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
 ?> 

La tabla:->

<tr>
      <td><?php echo $filas['Id'] ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $filas['gmail'] ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $filas['password'] ?></td>
      <td>
        <a href="">Editar</a>
        <a href="">Borrar</a>
      </td>
  </tr>
  <?php } 
?>
```

Le he cambiado códigos y no pasa nada en absoluto, me siguen y siguen apareciendo los mismo errores, y ya esta conectado a la base de datos, debería de traerme los datos que hay almacenados en ella pero cero...
Deberás estoy que tiro todo :C

Comment: Tu primer código recibe: `query` y luego `conexion`, eso esta mal, es al revés: https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php

Comment: ya hice esto y me aparece error :C

Comment: Una vez que corriges eso, ¿cuál es el nuevo error?

Comment: Probablemente esta respuesta te ayude: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/105641/warning-mysqli-query-expects-parameter-1-to-be-mysqli

Comment: este: Warning: mysqli_query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\xampp\htdocs\SalyArtOfi\logins.php on line 63

Comment: @Ann_Lu16 aqui tienes la solución a ese error: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/14130/por-qu%C3%A9-recibo-el-error-couldnt-fetch-mysqli

Comment: no sé, pero en el ciclo while estas haciendo un asignacion = y no es ==?

Comment: no @CRIS19N eso esta bien, si es asignación ahi

Comment: @BetaM siguió igual :C

Comment: ya comprobaste que tu consulta select se ejecute correctamente?, desconsola o un administrador de bd mysql?

Comment: @CRIS19N  eso es lo unico que no he hecho.. Lo voy a intentar..

Comment: y el problema es solo con esa consulta, o ya has hecho otras?, porque creo que hay una mejor forma que podiras emplear para que te conectes a la bd, pero tampoco veo el archivo de conexion, asi que no sé que exactamente esperar tu archivo de conexion

Comment: @CRIS19N Ya he hecho otras consultas y ninguna da, sale el mismo error, a parte de eso el archivo que tengo de conexión actualmente fue el único que me funciono bien...  :C

Comment: aqui te dejo en link de mysqli_query documentancion oficial https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php para que revises que estas haciendo mal.

Comment: @CRIS19N tanto mysqli pueden ser igual de inseguros o seguros dependiendo que tanto sabes de consultas preparadas

Comment: @CRIS19N voy a mirar el manual.. Porque deberás estoy que tiro todo :c

Comment: @CRIS19N Estoy tratando de tranquilizarme.... Sorry me altere y mucho... Me puedes contactar por este Email: sooann2020@gmail.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una opcion para resolver tu problema seria hacerlo de esta manera:

Conexion.php

```
<?php

    class Conexion
    {
        private $serverName="localhost";
        private $usuario="root";
        private $pwsd="";
        private $dbName="tubasededatos";
        private $link;
    
        function Open()
        {
            $this->link=mysqli_connect($this->serverName,$this->usuario,$this->pwsd);
            mysqli_set_charset($this->link, 'utf8');
            mysqli_select_db($this->link,$this->dbName);
        }
        function Execute($_sql)
        {
            date_default_timezone_set('America/La_Paz');
            $res=mysqli_query($this->link, $_sql);
            return $res;
        }
        function getCon()
        {
            return $this->link;
        }
    }
    
?>
```

---

Logins.php

```
  <?php
  require_once("Conexion.php");
  $conex=new Conexion;
  $conex->Open();

  $sql="SELECT Id,gmail,password FROM datosg";
  $res=$conex->Execute($sql);
  $table="<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th >#</th>
      <th >Id</th>
      <th >Gmail</th>
      <th >Password</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>";
  if(mysqli_num_rows($res)>0)
  {
      $row=mysqli_fetch_array($res);
      do{
          $table.="<tr>
          <td>".$row["Id"]."</td>
          <td>".$row["gmail"]."</td>
          <td>".$row["password"]."</td>
          <td>
            <a href=''>Editar</a>
            <a href=''>Borrar</a>
          </td>
        </tr>";      
      

        }while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res));
  }
  $table.="</tbody></table>";
  echo $table;
       
?>
```